# AndroidTv Leanback Correct way of updating rows and headers

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, android-diffutils

In light of [this article on medium](https://proandroiddev.com/android-tv-leanback-updating-rows-in-rowssupportfragment-b407dff3be4d) Which works perfectly fine when using **PageRows** in a **BrowseSupportFragment**. Things get ugly when **ListRow** is used instead of **PageRows** and the whole list and headers start to blink on every data update/set and the focus position is lost.

I've done some debugging and it looks like the payload generated by the **DiffUtil** in the **BrowseSupportFragment** is picked up by the **HeaderPresenter** and not the **ListRowPresenter**. Now the question is if this is a bug or normal behavior. And if the latter, what's the correct way of updating data inside a **BrowseSupportFragment** without blinks and focus losses?

The code to reproduce this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/ademirqueiroga/leanback-samples/pull/1)

What I've found is that in [this function](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:leanback/leanback/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/widget/ItemBridgeAdapter.java;l=298?q=file:androidx%2Fleanback%2Fwidget%2FItemBridgeAdapter.java%20class:androidx.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport)[image] at the beginning the ListRow type gets associated with [androidx.leanback.widget.RowHeaderPresenter](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:leanback/leanback/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/widget/RowHeaderPresenter.java?q=file:androidx%2Fleanback%2Fwidget%2FRowHeaderPresenter.java%20class:androidx.leanback.widget.RowHeaderPresenter&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) and this is maybe the cause the payload gets picked up by this Presenter.

Another clue could be the payload is picked up by the [ItemBridgeAdapter in the onBindViewHolder](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:leanback/leanback/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/widget/ItemBridgeAdapter.java;l=416?q=file:androidx%2Fleanback%2Fwidget%2FItemBridgeAdapter.java%20class:androidx.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) but only for the HeaderRowPresenter and for the following ListRowPresenter binding the payload is just empty.

[image: Function gets called for wrong presenter]

Comment: I've used `BrowseSupportFragment` with `ListRow` and never faced this issue you are referring, I suspect it's not related to using `ListRow`. Have you tried using `DiffCallback` from `androidx.leanback.widget` for updating items?

Comment: Thanks @mahdi, I'm actually using the DiffCallback from leanback already, for more information please check the comments in the medium article mentioned in the descriptions